# Write the function in the form $y=f(u)$ and $u=g(x)$. Then find $dy/dx$ as a function of $x$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$y=\left(3x^2-(8/x)-x\right)^9$$

I know that $y = u^9$ and then $u = 3x^2-\dfrac{8}{x}-x$, but then I do not know how to put it together to solve for $dy/dx$.

Comment: Is the denominator supposed to have $x-x$?

Comment: @Zhoe sorry! i forgot the parenthesis! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$y=f(u), \space u=g(x) \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

You would substitute u in for 
\begin{equation}u=3x^2-\frac{8}{x} - x\end{equation}
 giving you \begin{equation}y=u^9\end{equation} 
Deriving in terms of u with the chain rule\begin{equation}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}*\frac{du}{dx}\end{equation}
would give 
\begin{equation}9u^8*\frac{du}{dx}\end{equation} 
Plug u back into the equation